# Reset a dataframe to previous condition after clicking an actionButton() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which when the user starts typing a word in search `textInput()`. Then the user press Search and the dataframe is subseted according to this search. Then I would like the table to be reseted after clicking the `Reset` `actionButton()`.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
col1<-c("sd fgg","df dfg","fgh gdfg")
col2<-c("sd fgg","df dgfg","fgh gdfg")
col3<-c("sd fggg","dfg dfgg","fgghol gdfg")
df<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dataset Inventory"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    textInput("tt","search",""),
    actionButton("ser","Search"),
    actionButton("res","Reset")
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table<-renderDataTable({
  input$res
    datatable(
      d_new <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(grepl(isolate(input$tt), x))), ]
      
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `observeEvent`

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cntrl <- reactiveValues(n = 0)
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
      datatable(df)
    
  })
  observeEvent(input$ser,
               {
                 cntrl$n <- cntrl$n + 1
                 output$table<-renderDataTable({
                   datatable(
                     d_new <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(grepl(isolate(input$tt), x))), ]
                     
                   )
                 })
               }
               
               )
  observeEvent(input$res,
               {
                 cntrl$n <- 0
                 updateTextInput(session, "tt", value = "")
                  output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(df))
                
               })
  }
```

Comment: ok but the table needs to be displayed as soon as the app is launched for first time

Comment: @firmo23 Can you try the update.  I guess you can define the `output$table` outside the observeEvent to show the full data, and once you click 'ser' it does the subset and when you click on res, it resets to full data.  If that is the case, the change should work.

Comment: I m trying something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75165483/select-a-column-of-a-dataframe-to-subset-the-whole-dataframe-based-on-value-of-t