# Select a column of a dataframe to subset the whole dataframe based on value of this column in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

In the `shiny` app below I have already developed a method in which the user types a string in the first `textInput()` then he clicks `"Begin search"` in the `1st actionButton()` and subsets its dataset based on this string. Then he can click `Reset` to reset the dataset.

Now I want to add a 2nd search method in which the user will be able to select also a column, then type a string in the 2nd `textInput()`, click `Begin Search` on the 2nd `actionButton()` and subset the whole dataset based on this column, then clicks `Reset` to reset.

```
#Load libraries needed
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

#load ldataset
data_test_1_ <-structure(list(Dimension = c("environmental", "environmental", 
                                            "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", 
                                            "environmental", "environmental", "environmental", "environmental"
), Component = c("air quality", "air quality", "air quality", 
                 "water quality", "environmental hazards", "environmental hazards", 
                 "environmental hazards", "environmental hazards", "environmental hazards", 
                 "physical safety"), Indicator = c("outdoor", "outdoor", "indoor", 
                                                   NA, "Hazardous waste", "Heavy metals", "Pesticides", "Climate extremes", 
                                                   "Noise", "Traffic")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                           "tbl", "data.frame"))

#Dashboard
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dataset Inventory"),
  #left sidebar part
  dashboardSidebar(

    #the search box
    textInput("tt","Search whole dataset",""),
    
    #the button that triggers search
    actionButton("ser","Begin search"),
    
    tags$hr(),
    
    #select column to search
    uiOutput("column"),
    
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "p3",
      label = "Select Column to search",
      choices = colnames(data_test_1_),
      selected = colnames(data_test_1_[1]),
      multiple = F,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
    ),
    
    #the search box for column
    textInput("tt2","Search column",""),
    
    #the button that triggers search column
    actionButton("ser2","Begin search"),
    
    tags$hr(),
    
    #the button that triggers reset
    actionButton("res","Reset")
    
  ),
  #the main body part
  dashboardBody(
    #the table
    div(DT::dataTableOutput("table"), style = "font-size: 80%; width: 100%")
    
  )
)

#the server part
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  #a counter that is used for search and reseting
  cntrl <- reactiveValues(n = 0)
  
  #the reacive calling of the dynamic datatable
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(data_test_1_)
    
  })
  
  #the observer that activates the search button and searches all the felds of the dataset
  observeEvent(input$ser,
               {
                 cntrl$n <- cntrl$n + 1
                 output$table<-renderDataTable({
                   datatable(d_new <- data_test_1_[apply(data_test_1_, 1, function(x) any(grepl(isolate(input$tt), x))), ],escape = F
                             )
                 })
               }
               
  )
  
  #the observer that resets the dataset before the searching
  observeEvent(input$res,
               {
                 cntrl$n <- 0
                 updateTextInput(session, "tt", value = "")
                 output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(data_test_1_,
                                                           escape = F
                                                           ))
               })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you want to include searching functionality in the sidebar rather than directly in DT?

The quickest way to filter in DT is by adding the `filter` parameter. In any event here's one possible solution.

Rather than creating a new datatable every time a search is made. I've added a `reactiveValue` called `data_test` that contains the data. Then in each observeEvent all you need to do is modify `data_test$d` and renderDataTable will render the data that is pointed to that reactiveValue. I also added `filter = "top"` in case you haven't seen that before.

Lastly, in the second observeEvent where you want to search by column. I've set `input$p3` to the variable `col`. Then wrapped col with the bang bang operator `!!` and `rlang::sym`.

```
#the server part
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  #a counter that is used for search and reseting
  cntrl <- reactiveValues(n = 0)
  
  data_test = reactiveValues(
    d = data_test_1_
  )
  
  #the reacive calling of the dynamic datatable
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(data_test$d, filter = "top")
  })
  
  #the observer that activates the search button and searches all the felds of the dataset
  observeEvent(input$ser, {
    cntrl$n <- cntrl$n + 1
    data_test$d = data_test_1_[apply(data_test_1_, 1, function(x) any(grepl(isolate(input$tt), x))), ]
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$ser2, {
    col = input$p3

    data_test$d = data_test_1_ %>%
      filter(grepl(isolate(input$tt2), !!sym(col)))
  })
  
  #the observer that resets the dataset before the searching
  observeEvent(input$res, {
    cntrl$n <- 0
    updateTextInput(session, "tt", value = "")
    data_test$d = data_test_1_ # reset to original data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: nice I used filter though tnx